# What does "go pivot crazy" mean?

Tags: meaning

Here are three tips to create your marketing personas that use a mix of quantitative and qualitative methods of research:

1. Download your sales data and **go pivot crazy** in Excel

Your historic sales data is a rich source of customers with quantitative attributes. These are people that have already bought from you, and understanding why they did so is key. Look for the following attributes/activity

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a reference to "pivot tables", used for data analysis in Excel:
[ExcelEasy "pivot tables"](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html)

> Pivot tables are one of Excel's most powerful features. A pivot table allows you to extract the significance from a large, detailed data set.

"To go crazy" literally means to become insane, but it is used metaphorically meaning to enjoy something liberally, without restraint. In that use, it is similar to "have a ball", meaning "to enjoy yourself very much" (from the Cambridge dictionary definition).

So the intended meaning of "go pivot crazy" is "enjoy using pivot tables".